# Detecting biasing columns and removing bias in machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, regression, multiclass-classification

I came across a multivariate machine learning problem in which I need to detect the biasing column and remove the bias of that particular column in predicting final target variable.
train data-> [x1,x2,..xn,BiasColumn,y]  (BiasColumn does not contain all the X columns. Its only a fixed subset of X).
What should be the standard way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I thought of an approach as

1. Create classification model for detecting bias column
2. training a separate model for each value in BiasColumns. So in each
   model we will only take the training data subset having a particular
   biascolumn. We remove that column from X and train the model on y
3. for predictions we first detect the biascolumn and select the
   respective regression model for y